# Reverse engineer my models using EF Core Power tools issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-power-tools

I am creating an app and deciding to use EF 6.  I've only used EF Core up until now.  I want to do database first and use the EF 6 power tools.  However, when I download the EF 6 power tools and install it, I see an entry in Visual Studio showing EF Core Power tools. Why is that? I can't seem to install EF 6 Powertools from the NuGet Package Manager. I have to download the VSIX and install that.

Also, when I use the EF Core power tools to reverse engineer my models using EF Core Power tools, I get the following error:  Entity red underline with error:

> no overload for method e'Entity' takes 1 arguments.

Is this a problem with my fluent api syntax?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.MyEntity_ID);

            entity.Property(e => e.FieldName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(6);
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For EF6, use the [EF 6 Power Tools Community Edition](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EntityFramework6PowerToolsCommunityEdition) which works with Visual Studio 2015 and newer.

"EF Core Power Tools" are designed to work with EF Core, not EF6.